# Display User's Name in email

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email

I want to display the User's name in email. I have successfully sent an email to a mail id and now i want along with mail id i want to display user's name also.

Here is my code please help me as soon as possible.

```
Public Sub SendMail(ByVal EmailFrom As String, ByVal FromName As String, ByVal ToName As String, ByVal EmailTo As String, ByVal MailSubject As String, ByVal MailBody As String, ByVal Bcc As Int32)
    Try
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
        mail.From = New MailAddress(EmailFrom, FromName)
        mail.To.Add(EmailTo)
        mail.Subject = MailSubject
        mail.Body = MailBody

        mail.IsBodyHtml = True
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"   
        smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("example@gmail.com","abc")
        smtp.Send(mail)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: What do you mean by User's name in email? In body of an email or in From field ?

Comment: i m asking for "email to" field i have successfully displayed the email id to which i have sent an email but i want to display the name of user's also. for more info. i am going to paste a pic for this.

Comment: check out the answer posted by Rickjaah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same logic from the mail.From address.

```
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(EmailTo, ToName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I know it's C# but I hope you can translate to VB.NET):

`mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(EmailTo, EmailToName));`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ASp.NET Membership?? If so, you can try this

```
using System.Web.Security;

MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

if (user != null)
{
    string username = user.UserName;
    //set your label text here
}
```